# How can I get each property of class that has custom Attribute then show them in dropdown?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a class with some properties, some of them have custom Attribute,
I want to get them and put in Dictionary, then show them in dropdown, I've tried some Code but there are still some problems...

```
public class Constants
    {

    //FinancialVoucher
    [InCludeEventLog]
    private static readonly Guid financialVoucherEntityGuid = new Guid(0x83fd191f, 0x7bfe, 0x4050, 0xbb, 0xe8, 0x9d, 0x4e, 0x77, 0x66, 0xef, 0x2f); // {83FD191F-7BFE-4050-BBE8-9D4E7766EF2F}
    public static Guid FinancialVoucherEntityGuid
    {
      get { return financialVoucherEntityGuid; }
    }

    //CalculationCommandQueue
        private static readonly Guid calculationCommandQueueEntityGuid = new Guid(0xe4f847bc, 0xd65d, 0x4e41, 0x9c, 0xc8, 0x15, 0x65, 0x7b, 0xce, 0x8a, 0x5f);// {E4F847BC-D65D-4E41-9CC8-15657BCE8A5F}
        public static Guid CalculationCommandQueueEntityGuid
        {
            get { return calculationCommandQueueEntityGuid; }
        }

    //PayrollCalculationCommand
    [InCludeEventLog]
    private static readonly Guid payrollCalculationCommandEntityGuid = new Guid(0x50479cfe, 0xa9b4, 0x414b, 0xae, 0xfc, 0x0f, 0x6e, 0xee, 0x89, 0xfa, 0x5b); // {50479cfe-a9b4-414b-aefc-0f6eee89fa5b}
        public static Guid PayrollCalculationCommandEntityGuid
        {
            get { return payrollCalculationCommandEntityGuid; }
        }

///I've tried this:

Dictionary<Guid, string> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<Guid, string>();
      Type type = typeof(Constants);
      foreach (var item in type.GetProperties())
      {
        var getValidProperty = item.GetCustomAttributes();
        var entityGuid = Helper.GetGuid(item.GetValue(null));
        if (getValidProperty != null && getValidProperty.Any(c=> c.ToString() == "InCludeEventLog"))
          keyValuePairs.Add(entityGuid, item.Name);
      }
```

Comment: item.GetCustomAttributes(); doesn't work is there another way to Get properties from the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to look at the attributes on each property, not only on the class.
You should also look only at static properties, since you want to get the value of them without having a class instance.

```
var propertiesToInclude = 
        typeof(Constants).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static)
            .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<InCludeEventLog>() != null)
            .ToList();

// Since you are getting the value of static properties,
// you can pass null to GetValue.
// If you need the value of non-static properties, you need a class instance here.
var keyValues = propertiesToInclude.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(null));
```